# Force alle functions in shared library to be defined

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries

I want to write a shared library and I want to get a compiler/linker error if I forgot to implement some functions.

Consider the following case:

test.h

```
class Test {
    public:
    Test();
};
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"
```

main.cpp

```
#include "test.h"

int main() {
    new Test();
}
```

If I create a library with this command `gcc -c -fpic test.cpp && g++ -shared -o libtest.so -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--no-allow-shlib-undefined test.o` there is no error message, but the library is broken. Is there a way to force the creation of a not broken library?

Edit: adding additional flag, but doesn't change result

Comment: That will not help. Instead of writing the function, I will have to write the test implementation.

Comment: If you have some unit tests, they will fail if you don't have an implementation. How is that not helping?

Comment: Because my target is to get remembered if I forgot something. But it doesn't make a difference for me if i must remember to write a test or to write an implementation.

Comment: Does [-Wl,--no-allow-shlib-undefined](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#index-_002d_002dallow_002dshlib_002dundefined) make a difference?

Comment: If you aren't testing your functions, how do you know they are not "broken" (as in, buggy) even if you did remember to implement them?

Comment: I don't know, but I think that the compiler should ensure that the code can be compiled.  ( With your argument you could argue that compiler warnings arent useful, because without tests you do not know if the code is buggy)

Answer (score 0):

These codes have been modified:

test.h :

```
class Test {
    public:
    Test();
};
```

test.cpp :

```
#include "test.h"

Test::Test(){}  // you must implement the constructor
```

You must have to implement the constructor, and if not, you get an error "undefined reference to `Test::Test()'".

main.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
        Test* t = new Test(); // you must define a pointer

        cout << "test* was created: " << t << endl;

        delete t;
        t = nullptr;

        return 0;
}
```

Now all the code is OK. Then we create a shared-library with the following command:

```
g++ -shared -o test.so -fPIC test.cpp
```

Finally, we compile the main.cpp file at the same time as referring to the test.so shared-library and get the exe output, by the command below:

```
g++ -g main.cpp test.so -o test.exe
```

Comment: I think you do not understand my problem (or I do not understand your answer), but I know how to fix the code, but what I want to know is, how I can configure the compilation in such a way, that the compiler refuse to build the library without the implemented ctor.